# Expectation of a Uniform PDF

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

How do I find the expectation of the following pdf?

$f(x,y) = 1/\pi r^2$
, where $x^2+y^2 \leq r^2$

I've tried to integrate it on the bounds $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $\int \frac{x}{\pi r^2} dx$. However once I apply the net change theorem I get 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $0$ is the correct answer, but your method is unclear, so I can't say that you did things correctly...

Comment: You have not identified the random variable that you want to find the expectation of.